# SpringBoot app - server context Path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 , Java 8, maven

Here my security config

```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        final List<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
        if (activeProfiles.contains("dev")) {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(publicMatchers()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/iberia/list")
                .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }
```

in my `application.properties`

```
server.contextPath=/iberiaWebUtils
server.port=1234
```

But when I run the app at http://localhost:1234/iberiaWebUtils, instead of going to http://localhost:1234/iberiaWebUtils/login, the app. redirects to http://localhost:1234/login

I also tried with

```
server.context-path=/iberiaWebUtils
```

with the same result

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue you are facing.. I have configured project with spring-security and thymeleaf with springboot... Please share your detailed configuration so it will be helpful to debug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting from **Spring Boot 2.0.0 M1** servlet-specific server properties  were moved to `server.servlet`:

[image]
<sup>[Spring Boot 2.0.0 M1 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#spring-boot-200-m1-release-notes)</sup>

Therefore, you should use the `server.servlet.context-path` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.loginProcessingUrl("/iberiaWebUtils/login")` after `loginPage("/login")`

```
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(publicMatchers()).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login")    
            .loginProcessingUrl("/iberiaWebUtils/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/iberia/list")
            .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();
```