# 4 paths in application.properties

Tags: spring

What are the differences between the following 4 paths in application.properties file in Spring project and not Spring Boot?

1. application.path
2. servlet.path
3. server.servlet.context-path
4. spring.mvc.servlet.path

Answer (score 0):

These examples are all shown assuming your application is running on localhost, port 8080.

`server.servlet.context-path` defines the context, if not set then it's the root context (/).  If you set this to `foo`, your app will listen on `http://localhost:8080/foo`.  Information can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.servlet.context-path)

`spring.mvc.servlet.path` sets the path to the dispatch servlet, it immediately follows the `server.servlet.context-path`.  If you set this to `bar` and don't have `server.servlet.context-path` set, your app will listen on `http://localhost:8080/bar`.  If you have the `server.servlet.context-path` set to `foo` and `spring.mvc.servlet.path` set to `bar`, your app will be listening on `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar`.  Information can be found
[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.servlet.path)

I am unaware of the properties `application.path` or `servlet.path`.  That's not to say that you aren't seeing them in an application.properties file somewhere, just that they don't have any meaning.

Comment: I'm confused with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432524/springboot-app-server-context-path.  Is server.path = spring.mvc.servlet.path and server.context-path = server.servlet.context-path.

Comment: any comments or let me know. server.servlet.context-path  (old property: server.context-path)  and spring.mvc.servlet.path (old property: server.path)...is that right?